# Edit Product Template on Shop template of Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, templates, woocommerce

I have a wordpress website with woocommerce deployed. I want to override some of the layout and the way each product is displayed on the shop page. I am doing this by creating a child template. I am able to override some functions, but am unable to find which file I need to edit, in order to modify how the thumbnails are displayed. In other words, the thumbnails shown in the following file...

woocommerce\templates\content-product.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just copy `templates\content-product.php` files to your theme folder; it will override the default template and do whatever changes you need. Visit WooCommerce official [documentation](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/) for further details.

Comment: Like I said, I already copy-pasted it. It calls an action - woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title, which draws the thumbnail on the shop page and shows the image in it. I need to find the function behind that so I can modify the way the thumbnail is populated. I am unable to find this part.

Comment: Did you try `woocommerce_product_thumbnails` or `woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html` filter?. [Here] (https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html) all woocommerce hook listed. can search for `thumbnail` and see their code sample in Github.

Comment: The single-product templates that the above URL refers to is for the product detail page, I need to edit the thumbnail on this page...

http://foart.space/shop/

Comment: I had the right file all along, but got confused due to something. It ended up like searching for my car keys all over my house, while having them in my pocket